# Do the partitions created by a graph cut need to be connected?

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question regarding graph cuts in graph theory. Suppose that there exists a graph G and I was to implement a graph cut to partition the vertices in graph G into two subsets A and B. Would the vertices in each of these partitions need to be connected? Are there any further requirements that need to be satisfied by the cut and the resulting partitions?

Thank you.

Comment: There's no such requirements.  According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory), a cut is just a partition of $V(G)$ into 2 subsets $A$ and $B$.  That's it, nothing else.